# How do I display the text in a text area elsewhere in my webpage(blog)?

Tags: html, web, comments

I am making a comments posting form for my blog, but I do not know how to display the text in my page.

So far I have got this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form style="margine:0px" method="post" target="view" id="WriteItForm">
<table border="2" bordercolor="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Comments</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea id="text_area" cols="20">
   --New Comment--
      </textarea>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
<table border="2" bordercolor="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>There Is Currently No Comments</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
<p id="draw_here"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

It give out an area of text like the one `<a href="http://www.zubrag.com/tools/html-password-protector-encoder.php">here</a>`.

The function of the form is to make it add the text in the textarea to my post when you click the submit button (which I do not know how to do either).

I want it to add some text into the post when you click the button, so that other people can read the comments, and so that I can use them to improve my page.

Comment: Please add information to your question such as the back-end processing (the form action) you will be employing, and what problems you are encountering in that.

Comment: if you think just adding a form to your blog page will be a comment posting system, you are not true and  on the right way, this is not so simple. if not, so explain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to MDN's 'Learn HTML' page here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/html

There are so many things wrong here I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I am a begginer at html, so I suppose that your right.             What was wrong anyway?

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude. I just know that you'd be a lot better off knowing the basics. It looks like you've already corrected the things that I saw yesterday. Although you have misspelled `margin` in your form style declaration.